# Can't insert a record with Number(16, 2) field type

Tags: formula-field, decimal, number

I've to insert, for my test method, an `Invoice__c` object with a value of `Amount_Due__c` more than 0. This field is a `Formula (Number) with 2 Decimal Places` field with this syntax `Invoice_Amount__c - Collected_Amount__c`.

```
Collected_Amount__c is a simple Number(18, 0) field
Invoice_Amount__c is Number(16, 2) field
```

`Invoice_Amount__c` is not related to anything, neither is `Collected_Amount__c`.

**My insert statement:**

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < bulkDataValue; i++){
    forCollectionInvoices_tst.add(new Invoice__c(Quotation__c = newQuotation_tst[i].Id, Invoice_Amount__c = 20.00, Collected_Amount__c = 1));
}
```

---

**My debuging process came with this results:**
What's happening is, I was able to insert the desired `Collected_Amount__c` value, but `Invoice_Amount__c` value still equal to 0.

---

> I made a goofing around move with inserting a negative value to
>   `Collected_Amount__c` and it **works**, but I need to insert right logical
>   acceptable values.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Formula fields are evaluated when an SObject is queried not when an SObject is modified in memory. So in the past, if you needed the result of a formula field evaluation in your business logic or in a test you had to re-query. But recently the [SObject.recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method was added:

> Recalculates all formula fields on an sObject, and sets updated field
>   values. Rather than inserting or updating objects each time you want
>   to test changes to your formula logic, call this method and inspect
>   your new field values. Then make further logic changes as needed.

Calling that may solve your problem.

(Not sure this matches all your symptoms.)

Comment: The formula field is responding to me, but my problem is: I'm not able to insert or change the value of `Invoice_Amount__c`, and I'm not sure why!

Comment: @MAZux OK I'll delete this in a little while. If you are inserting a value of say 20 but when you query again you get zero then I assume there is a workflow rule or trigger that e.g. maps all positive values to zero.

Comment: There isn't any validation rules or triggers related with this field or the other mentioned fields. @Keith